# norm of $x \in \mathbb R^d$ is in Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-integral, weak-derivatives

> For which values of $\alpha, k,p,d$ is  $$ \|x\|^\alpha \in
>  \textrm{W}^{k,p} (B(0,1)) \quad ?  $$
>
> where $\displaystyle{ \textrm{B}(0,1) = \{x \in \mathbb R^d :
>  \|x\|<1\}}$

This is an exercise from the book of J.Jost "Postmodern Analysis". It is in Chapter 20 ,page 285. In the examples of this chapter proves that $\|x\|^\alpha  \in \textrm{W}^{1,p} (B(0,1))$ for $(\alpha -1)p +d >0$. But in this problem I don't know even how to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, the function must belong to $L^p(B(0,1))$. Did you check this? Then, you must compute all the derivatives up to order $k$, and check if they belong to $L^p(B(0,1))$. Of course, since your function is radially symmetric, you can take advantage from the formula $$\int_{B(0,1)} f(\|x\|)\, dx = \omega_{n} \int_0^1 f(r) r^{n-1}\, dr,$$ where $\omega_n$ is the volume of the sphere $S^{n-1}$.